# Loading training plans on to Elemnt Bolt for free

Tags: training

How would one go about loading training plans onto a Wahoo Elemnt Bolt without using an app like trainer road or training peaks? Is this even possible? I'd like to use a free tool on my laptop such as Golden Cheetah or something similar.. I'm not looking to create complicated workout plans, just simple interval sessions that I can follow out on the road.

Comment: It's not currently officially supported, but I found some info you might find useful here:
https://ergdb.org/load-workouts-onto-your-wahoo-elemnt-on-a-mac/
Kept as a comment rather than an answer as I think wahoo will improve support and outdate it rather quickly

Comment: @AndyP fantastic - it works!! :) It's a little fiddly, but that ergdb thing is really easy to use. Now I can put together a plan and execute it outside, woohoo.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get workout intervals to trigger based on location.. I'm guessing not, but it'd be really cool to be able to do that.. is there somewhere you can make suggestions to wahoo?

Comment: @JohnHunt There are the Strava Segments which get triggered when you get to their start. I'm not sure about the use case of workout intervals being triggered by location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per @andyP's comment:

> It's not currently officially supported, but I found some info you might find useful here: ergdb.org/load-workouts-onto-your-wahoo-elemnt-on-a-mac Kept as a comment rather than an answer as I think wahoo will improve support and outdate it rather quickly

This worked fine, the file transfer app on the mac is a bit flakey, but I got my workout on there just fine.

Comment: Still working as of 2020-06-10. Even the file deletion works without any workarounds.
Could you please include the described steps here so that this answer is complete, even when the mentioned website is deleted?

Comment: Interestingly ergdb is now trainerday which is a bit like trainerroad except far, far cheaper. It's not as feature packed but it is a great compromise that I have subscribed to.